# concerning about write function,

Tags: c, linux, unix, digits

I wanna show all digits numbers, like "0123456789"

in Unix, I used vim
and typed the code, like this way

```
    #include <unistd.h>

     void ft_print_numbers(void)
     {
         int i;

         i=0;
         while(i <= 9)
         {
             write(1, &i, 1);
             i++;
         }

    }

     int main()
     {
         ft_print_numbers();
     }
```

but, the result which I saw, was nothing...
I can't see anything but the blank...

What's wrong with my code?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: To help people with helping you, please [edit] to turn the shown text (it is not code) into a [mre]. For that you need to fix the syntax broken by the numbers at the start of each line. Turn them into comments or delete them please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not add line numbers in your code. This prevents it from using c&p and compiling it. What output did you expect?

Comment: by the rule, I can't use 'for' function and I have to use 'write' function

Answer (score 2):

There are *no* known encoding scheme where the integer digits are equal to their character.

Using the most common encoding available, ASCII, the value for the *character* `'0'` is the integer value `48`.

Now for the good news: The C specification requires that all digits must be encoded sequentially. That means `'1'` will be `49`, etc. until `'9'` which is `57`.

So you can loop from `'0'` to `'9'` and write that value instead:

```
for (int8_t c = '0'; c <= '9'; ++c)
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, &c, 1);
```

<sub>[Note that I changed the [*magic number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) `1` to the symbol `STDOUT_FILENO`, as as magic numbers make code hard to read, understand and maintain]</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your help, but by the rule, I can't use 'for' function and I have to use 'write' function

Comment: @Joseph Then you just translate the `for` *loop* (it's not a function) into a corresponding `while` loop. And I still use `write`, just not using the magic number `1`.

Comment: So... What is magic number??? what does it mean? and STDOUT_FILENO which you stated, What is it?

Comment: @Joseph Please follow the link in my question. `STDOUT_FILENO` is a preprocessor macro that expands to `1`, but where `1` could mean anything or nothing special, `STDOUT_FILENO` is readable and understandable and immediatley recognizable as the standard output (`STDOUT`) file descriptor (`FILENO`).

Comment: @Joseph The phrase "magic number" is used to describe a number which appears in a program without explanation.  Using a standard-defined preprocessor macro makes the code easier to read and incurs no additional runtime overhead.

Comment: You have to use `write`? I was about to answer to use `printf` instead.